# Error 500 when PHP attempting to access sqlite DB in /var/

Tags: apache, sqlite, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I'm attempting to set up a site which uses sqlite3 on a Digital Ocean droplet (I have SSH root access) and I've created a `/var/databases/myapp` directory on my Ubuntu VPS to store the sqlite3 db.

However, after uploading a PHP script to test DB access, I get a 500 error. The PHP script is just intended to make sure I can access the sqlite3 db, and looks like this:

*myfile.php*

```
$dir = 'sqlite:/var/databases/myapp/mydb.sqlite3';
$dbh  = new PDO($dir) or die("There was a problem accessing database. Please contact the admin.");

$stm = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM my_table');
$stm->execute();
$results = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($results as $result):
    var_dump($result);
endforeach;
```

When I attempt to access this file at *myfile.php*, I get a 500 error. Can anyone suggest what I may have configured incorrectly that would prevent the PHP file from accessing the database?

I've attempted to activate PHP error logging using the instructions [here](https://davidwinter.me/enable-php-error-logging/), but the error_log file I created is empty so I don't think I've configured it correctly.

As someone with little experience setting up servers, I'm very grateful for any help!

EDIT:
I found the following in my apache2 error.log
[Date time] [:error] [pid xxxx] [client xxx.xx.xxx.x:xxxxx] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in /var/www/html/testme.php:5\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/testme.php(5): PDO->__construct('sqlite:/var/dat...')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/testme.php on line 5

I think this means I need to install the `pdo_sqlite` extension.

Comment: You mention you created the directory - how about `mydb.sqlite3`? Can you run the same query against it using sqlite on the command line?

Comment: You really need to see the error logs.

Comment: Check your Apache logs as well /var/log/apache2

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php7-sqlite` (or php5-sqlite)